# Is it possible to set default settings for configurable products on the store view in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a configurable product which allows buyers to select both dimensions and number of drawers for storage boxes.

I would like the drop downs on the store view to set each value to the default value for their related attribute. The default values for each attribute has been set in the Admin area, but the product options still show the "please select" value on page load.